# Visual Studio 2019 solution with 2 projects, one Angular and one with typescript. Getting compile on save to work

Tags: angular, typescript, visual-studio-2019

We are using Visual Studio 2019 (full version, not VS Code). We have a solution with a few projects in it.

One has Angular code which we build using the usual 'ng build',

The other is an ASP.NET MVC project with some typescript files in a Script folder, some in the Areas folder and some in Views.

What used to happen was that when we changed a typescript file it would compile straight away. Now it only compiles when doing a full build.

The Compile on Save has been enabled in the project properties. I have also tried using a `tsconfig.json` file at the root of the project:

```
{
    "compileOnSave": true,
    "compilerOptions": {
        "noImplicitAny": false,
        "noEmitOnError": false,
        "removeComments": false,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "target": "es5",
        "module": "commonjs"
    },
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules",
        "typings",
        "*.d.ts"
    ],
    "typeAcquisition": {
        "enable": false,
        "exclude": [ "node" ]
    }
}
```

I suspect this is because of the Angular project that has been added. However unloading or deleting the project doesn't fix the issue

Answer (score 0):

If you have a separate command window with 'ng build --watch' running then Visual Studio doesn't compile the ts on save, even though it's in a different directory.

So if this happens then stop the Angular build while you're working on the Typescript.
You don't need to close Visual Studio but give it a few seconds, then you should see that Visual Studio is compiling your Typescript on save again